# How do I set a function to repeat until a Button is pressed

Tags: android, button, repeat

Given the following code:

```
package com.buttonsound;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class buttonsound extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final MediaPlayer mpButton=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.button_click);
        Button buttonsound=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonsound.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
                while(me.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    mpButton.start();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How do I start a function and set it to repeat until a Button is pressed which terminates the operation. The above code simply repeats even after the button is released.

Answer (score 4):

You're never calling `stop()`, of course it'll keep playing. Your while loop is calling `start()` multiple times, you shouldn't be doing that. Think of it like any other Media Player -- you don't continually press Play to listen to the whole track, it continues until you tell it otherwise.

Try something like this instead:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    switch(me.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(!mpButton.isPlaying()) mpButton.start();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(mpButton.isPlaying()) mpButton.stop();
            break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: As an aside, naming a MediaPlayer `mpButton` is just asking for confusion down the line; just sayin'. ;)

Comment: class hello extends Thread{
    public void run(){
     Boolean btnIsPressed=false;
     while(!btnIsPressed){
      mpButton.start();
}
    
   
    }}
   
   final hello p=new hello();
  
buttonsound.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
  
  
   btnIsPressed = true;

  
  
  
  return false;
 }
});

Comment: Why did you post this comment?

Answer (score 0):

hi you can do something like this :

```
Boolean btnIsPressed = false;
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

and add a thread  , and in the method run add this code :

```
@Override
public void run(){
      while(!btnIsPressed){
          myfunction();
      }
}
```

finally , in your method onCreate  , add a listener to change the value of your boolean to true like this :

```
btn.addOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

   @Overrride
   public void onClick(View v){
      btnIsPressed = true;
   }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: btnIsPressed doesnt work in the ontouch listener method. it says cannot refer to a non final variable in this method

Comment: @sudhman : i've set an OnClickListener , because you want a button pressed , not touched ,if you want an onTouchListener , you should add an onTouchListener and try it ,
for the error : cannot refer to a non fnal variable , add your code and we will resolve it , that's because ur method :runOnUIThread() needs final variables ; that's all

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about how to repeat something in mediaplayer just

```
 mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
 mediaPlayer.start();
```